# Docker installation on Windows 10 Home

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am unable to install Docker for Desktop in Windows 10 Home edition. I tried some work around. But nothing worked out. Has anyone installed in Win 10 home? 
Please advise the procedure. Thanks in advance.

1. Executed this InstallHyperV.bat

pushd “%~dp0” dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages*Hyper-V*.mum >hyper-v.txt for /f %%i in (‘findstr /i . hyper-v.txt 2^>nul’) do dism /online /norestart /add-package:”%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i” del hyper-v.txt Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V -All /LimitAccess /ALL pause

2. Executed this InstallContainers.bat

pushd "%~dp0" dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages*containers*.mum >containers.txt for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . containers.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i" del containers.txt Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Containers -All /LimitAccess /ALL pause

3. Restarted the pc.
4. In the Registry Editor, edited  \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion
   Right-click on EditionID and Click Modify
   Changed Value Data to Professional.
5. Tried to install docker for desktop exe file.

After sometime, it throws an error as *hyper-v* is not found on this pc.

Comment: have you tried to turn on VTx ( in BIOs) and Hyper-V of window ?

Comment: I executed systeminfo.exe command and system showed all of the requirements are YES. From Turn windows features on or off, i don't find hyper-v option available. Only option available was Windows Hypervisor and I checked it and tried installing. I didn't change any bios settings.

Comment: after modify changed value data to professional you need to log out or restart and try to install docker again.

Comment: Yes I did restart. But after sometime during docker installation I got an error saying *hyper-v* is not available in this pc.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 home doesn't support Hyper-V.

From the the [hyper-v requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#check-requirements), you need either Windows 10 Enterprise, Pro, or Education.

Comment: Just to add windows container do not need hyper b but still wont work with windows home

Comment: Yes I understand that but there should be some work around or solution right?

Answer (score 0):

1. you just can’t use the Hyper-V version of docker but you can use the
   VirtualBox version.
2. And you can upgrade your windows edition to
   professional or enterprise or education.

Comment: Thank  you for the advice.  I am working on the solution. I will update the steps once completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the Hyper-V way you can use Docker with WSL2(Windows Subsystem for Linux) for Windows 10 Home.

1. Go to Settings -> Update&Security -> Windows Insider Program and enroll for the 'Slow' track of windows insider.
2. Enable WSL from instructions given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10
3. Upgrade to WSL2 from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel
4. Download this version of Docker which supports WSL2 during installation itself : https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20Desktop%20Installer.exe
5. Check the boxes to use WSL2 instead of Hyper-V.