# Force docker for Windows to use Hyper-V instead of WSL2

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

Since version 2.3.0.2 docker desktop is able to be installed on Windows 10 Home edition, because it can use windows feature WSL2 instead of Hyper-V. Windows 10 Home edition does not come with Hyper-V installed.

I am restricted to Windows 10 Home edition and the project I'm working on does not function with WSL2 as the docker-for-windows backend; only with Hyper-V. I installed Hyper-V on Windows 10 Home using the batch script below, but am unable to switch from WSL to Hyper-V in docker.

The option is greyed out.

[image: The option is greyed out.]

**How do I force docker to use Hyper-V instead of WSL2 on Windows 10 Home?**

Batch script to install Hyper-V on Windows Home:

```
pushd "%~dp0"dir /b %SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\*Hyper-V*.mum >hyper-v.txt

for /f %%i in ('findstr /i . hyper-v.txt 2^>nul') do dism /online /norestart /add-package:"%SystemRoot%\servicing\Packages\%%i"

del hyper-v.txt

Dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All /LimitAccess /ALL
```

Comment: How did you manage to install Hyper-V on Windows Home in the first place?

Comment: I appended the batch script i used to the original post.

Comment: I also enabled virtualization technology in BIOS, so Hyper-V should be able to run.

Comment: Did you verify that Hyper-V is actually working? Have you tried creating and running a VM with it? If you did and it does work, you should try reinstalling Docker. Hopefully, it’ll detect the presence of Hyper-V. If not, it’s possible that Docker for Windows checks the edition of Windows rather than whether Hyper-V is available and/or enabled.

Answer (score 0):

To install Docker for Windows using Hyper-V in Home Edition, registry hack is needed to pretend system as Pro Edition.

```
REG ADD "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v EditionId /T REG_EXPAND_SZ /d Professional /F
```

(from some Chinese forums without source of it)

This would overwrite the origin value of the `EditionId` key, though it does little to the activation license. If you change the value back, the checkbox would turn to grey which OP mentions. However it will still using the Hyper-V backend. (You can check it by entering Hyper-V Console and open DockerDesktopVM to see if it's working)

To re-enable the checkbox if you want to checkout WSL2, quit Docker Desktop via tray icon, set the hack and start Docker Desktop.

Tested on Windows 11 22H2 Home Edition

---

Similar questions:

[Docker for windows 10 home edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66213901/docker-for-windows-10-home-edition)

[Can't install Docker : Docker Desktop requires Windows 10 Pro or Enterprise version 15063 to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60809467/cant-install-docker-docker-desktop-requires-windows-10-pro-or-enterprise-vers)

(This question here)

[Docker installation on Windows 10 Home](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60427939/docker-installation-on-windows-10-home)

Answer (score -1):

*This is likely due to a docker software update, docker will automatically use WSL even if the previous Docker version was initially enabled for Hyper-V.*

**To fix this:** 
**Uninstall and re-install docker and follow procedure for Hyper-V usage.**