# Docker for windows 10 home edition

Tags: windows, docker

For installing docker on windows home edition , there are two options if I don't want to run virtual machine.

Which is better :

1. installing docker desktop ?
2. installing using wsl2 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to answer which one is better but instead present some points you should consider before choosing one. However, if you're using Windows Home Edition, I'm afraid your choice is to either:

1. upgrade to Windows Pro and install Docker with the original Windows backend
2. install WSL2, then install Docker with the WSL2 backend

This is mentioned on the Docker website. Instructions for Windows Home/WSL2 [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/) and for Windows Pro/Non-WSL2 [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

**Bind mount performance**

If you care about bind-mounts, where you share a directory between the host OS filesystem (Windows) and the container filesystem (usually Linux), you'll want to compare performance between these two options.

If you want faster bind-mount performance on WSL2, you should mount shared files in the Linux filesystem (the part of your system dedicated to WSL2) for mounting. So you'd want to use `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\<user name>\Project` instead of `C:\Users\<user name>\Project`. Docker has more info about this [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#best-practices) and Microsoft has more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#performance-across-os-file-systems).

**Start time**

Other points mentioned on the Docker website include that Docker has a faster cold-start time with the WSL2 backend compared to the previous version.

**Changing Docker system settings**

Using WSL2, you'll also have to modify the WSL2 configuration if you want to reduce the amount of memory Docker can use for example. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config#configure-global-options-with-wslconfig) as referenced from the Docker on WSL2 [best practices](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/#best-practices).

Answer (score 1):

I see no two options, at least in the terms you used stating the questions.

On Windows 10 you install Docker Desktop and this *can have* WSL2 as backend.

On Windows 10 Home, specifically, you can install [Docker Desktop with WSL2 backend](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/).

For reference see ["Install Docker Desktop on Windows Home" documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install-windows-home/) where *only one option* is described, and not two.